# Problem with MpegTs file while playing with VLC

Tags: video, video-processing, vlc, mpeg-2, mpeg2-ts

I have created mpegts file which contains h264 elementary stream.
I am facing a pixelation problem with my encoded file when I try to play it using VLC.
Can anyone help me in finding what is going wrong with my mepgts encoder.
I have uploaded the file at http://www.4shared.com/get/KvCskAVx/problem1.html.

Kind Regards,
Ven

Comment: I have fixed this issue..the problem was with PES_packet_length which I was setting greater than 65535.(if the Elementary stream size is greater than 65535,we should set PES_packet_length to zero(see ITU-T Rec. H.222.0 (05/2006),page no 33)

Comment: You can answer and accept your own question

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue..the problem was with PES_packet_length which I was setting greater than 65535.(if the Elementary stream size is greater than 65535,we should set PES_packet_length to zero(see ITU-T Rec. H.222.0 (05/2006),page no 33)